# Trying to use node.js and passport, but authentication page just times out

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using passport to do a local authentication.  It's pretty simple right now, just a simple login form and login route.  It works perfectly when running on my mac, but when I upload it to a rackspace server and try it, I get a timeout when trying to submit the form to /login.

Relevant code (let me know if i need to add more):

```
//Passport SETUP 
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    console.log("serialized");
    done(null, user.username);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (username, done) {
    console.log("deserialized");
    user = users.getUserByUsername(username);
    done(null, user);
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function (username, password, done) {
    users.loginUser(username, password, function(err, user) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (user) {
            return done(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect Login.'});
        }
    });
  }
));

//middleware
var loginRequired = function(req, res, next){
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
  res.redirect('/');
};

//using passport
app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/game',
                                    failureRedirect: '/',
                                    failureFlash: true })
);

//page that i want to eventually get to
app.get('/game', loginRequired, function(req, res){
    res.render('game', {title:"Game Page"});
});
```

note - the deserialize right now is just a cheater that returns the user object, eventually it'll be a callback and all that :).

Answer (score 0):

:( after throwing in console.logs everywhere I found out that it was mysql.  The user wasn't created on the server.  Not sure why mysql-simple-pool didn't error out, but it didn't.